# What is a good structure for an enterprise agile transformation proposal?

Tags: agile, agile-coach

I have been asked to create a 7-slide presentation or 7-page document to a newly formed Agile Taskforce, who reports directly to the CEO of a large organisation.

The organisation wants to cascade Agile ways of working across the organisation led by this task force, working hand in hand with departments and teams across the group. Think pollen spreading over a field or hub and spoke.

Their objective is to simplify their products and processes with a focus on the customer and are open to experimentation.

They want the Taskforce to be diverse in type and amount of Agile experience.

They want me to use the presentation to show them how I would build this Taskforce, how my experience would be useful for this Taskforce i.e. what role would I want to play and how this Taskforce would role out the objectives mentioned above. They want it to be about practical experience and less about Agile buzzwords.

So my question here is if you have some pointers for how I could structure this document. I have a lot of experience just not sure what the best way is to essentially show how an enterprise agile transformation would roll out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to consider include:

#### Communications Plan

- Who are you going to communicate with
- How frequently
- What mediums to use

#### Training Plan

- What types of training
- Who will be trained
- When training will take place
- Training teams vs mentoring

#### Organisation

- How will the transformation team be organised
- Will they operate using an Agile framework (Scrum, Kanban, etc.)
- Who will act as the product owner/manager for the work

#### Scope

- What will be in scope / out of scope
- For example, will engineering methods be in scope
- What about reporting? Governance? Compliance?